# can I make my iOS app only available on iPhone 6 and later models?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to make my iOS app only available on iPhone 6 and later devices. The UI is too big for the smaller 5s and 5 screens. is this something I do in Xcode or when I submit to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**, no you can't restrict certain screen resolutions.

**Slightly longer version**. Theoretically, it's possible to rule out iPhone 5S by adding a requirement of `ARKit` into `Info.plist`. But that will also get rid of 6 and 6+. And given that there's iPhone SE with an `1136 x 640` resolution, which supports ARKit, this is not an option either.

You could go even further and say that your app requires an NFC (which limits devices to iPhone 7(+)/8(+)/X), but then there are rumors of iPhone SE2, who knows if Apple is going to add an NFC chip to it (and it probably will).

Check out the [device compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1) matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot limit availability of an iOS app by device — only by minimum system version. Since iOS 11 runs on the iPhone 5s, your app will be available for that device.